# Gulp browsersync often prints error when changing SASS

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

I have a problem with my Gulp configuration. There is often a situation when I change SASS styles and this error occurs:

```
[20:05:47] Starting 'sass'...
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
app\themes\mytheme\assets\scss\styles.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: _header.
```

I think it happens because other .pipe tasks run and this change cannot load, however, sometimes it strangely works.

Any advice?

**My Gulp file:**

```
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

browserSync.init({
     proxy:"http://localhost/artfoods/o-firmie/"
});

gulp.watch("./app/themes/mytheme/assets/scss/**/*.scss", ['sass']);
gulp.watch("./app/themes/mytheme/pages/**/*.php").on('change', 
browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
return gulp
    .src(input)
    .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(prefix('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(output))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());

});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Comment: what text editor you use?

Comment: i use sublime text

Comment: Add this to your user settings (preferences>settings) `"atomic_save": true.